# Regex patten cutom implementation

Tags: regex

`10001.000.01.01-A-AB` - I need to write regex in the following format. this is taking care of until numbers decimal need to add characters

```
/^\d{4,6}(\.\d{3})(\.\d{2}(\.\d{2})?(\.\d{2})?)?$/ 

0001.000-A
0001.000.01-A
0001.000.01.01-A
0001.000.01.01-A-AB
10001.000.01.01-A-AB
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: The format of this makes it hard to understand. Can you clean it up some? I fear it will be closed if you can't make it more understandable.

Comment: Also, what are the square `` characters?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): What is the input data? what output(s) do you expect? what did you try so far?

Comment: I'm looking for regex pattern, in the following format  0001.000-A or 0001.000.01-A or 0001.000.01.01.01 OR 0001.000.01-A-AB

Answer (score 1):

It seems you may use

```
^\d{4,6}\.\d{3}(?:\.\d{2}(?:\.\d{2})?(?:\.\d{2})?)?(?:-[A-Z]+(?:-[A-Z]+)?)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/egHtv9/3)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\d{4,6}` - 4 to 6 digits
- `\.\d{3}` - a `.` and 3 digits
- `(?:\.\d{2}(?:\.\d{2})?(?:\.\d{2})?)?` - an optional group matching

  - `\.\d{2}` - a dot and 2 digits
  - `(?:\.\d{2})?` - an optional sequence of `.` and 2 digits
  - `(?:\.\d{2})?` - ibid.
- `(?:-[A-Z]+(?:-[A-Z]+)?)?` - an optional non-capturing group matching 1 or 0 occurrences of:

  - `-` - a hyphen
  - `[A-Z]+` - 1 or more ASCII uppercase letters
  - `(?:-[A-Z]+)?` - an optional sequence of:

    - `-` - a hyphen
    - `[A-Z]+` - 1 or more ASCII uppercase letters
- `$` - end of string

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I will try

Comment: @RamamohanReddy: "Did not work" does not help me to understand what the problem is. Please show what you are doing, update your question with the code you used.

Comment: Good examples:
0001.000-A
0001.000.01-A
0001.000.01.01-A
0001.000.01.01-A-AB
10001.000.01.01-A-AB
Bad examples (display an error):
001.000-A
0001.00-A
0001.000.1-A
0001.000.01.1-A
0001.000.01.01-A.AB
10001.000.01.01.A-AB it can be any letter. not A or B

Comment: Thank you for the hlep, Couple of conditions are failing 0001.000.00.01
0001.000.00
0001.000 looks like it is looking for alphates as mandatory, they are optional

Comment: Wrap them all with an optional non-capturing group - https://regex101.com/r/egHtv9/3